# Como fazer alteração em banco de dados sem ter uma chave primária clara?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, vb.net

Preciso de um método para fazer alteração de dados em uma tabela do SQL Server.

Segundo meu cliente, **todos** os dados da tabela podem ser alterados. Por ter essa possibilidade, fico sem um referencial fixo e único para o banco saber qual o dado que será alterado.

```
UPDATE tabela SET campo = 1 
WHERE outro_campo = 5
```

Meu cliente sugeriu a criação de um código em tela, que ficaria invisível para o usuário, para o banco usar como referencial de alteração, mas ficando invisível, o usuário não tem como inseri-lo, e para exibir esse código quando a tela é aberta, não dá, porque não existem dados nos campos para usar um SELECT.

Comment: Catharina, o ID como PK, você sabe que é único por ser **auto_increment**. Você tem que ter uma tela no seu sistema para inserir os dados, mas não precisa inserir o ID. Mas caso queira mostrar um campo na tela para mostrar o ID do registro que será cadastrado, faça apenas um `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABELA`  e soma + 1 para mostrar no campo. O **MAX** vai pegar o último ID cadastrado. Depois para fazer a alteração de algum registro, apenas faça um `SELECT usando o WHERE = ? ID` e retorne os valores dos campos na tela de alteração.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Uma técnica básica de criação de tabelas em banco de dados é ter um uma coluna `ID` como chave primária, assim os dados ficam livre para serem trabalhados como quiser. Este identificador que será obviamente único e auto-incrementado é necessário para a aplicação mas não para o usuário. Em geral o usuário nem sabe que ele existe, é algo absolutamente interno. Exemplo:

```
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/DML/Identity.sql).

Comment: Sim, todas as minhas tabelas possuem uma PK, e também conheço o conceito delas... Mas como posso apontar isso em código? Se é algo interno, ou como costumo chamar "apenas para organizar os dados", e o usuário sequer sabe que existe, que referencial eu teria em minhas telas pra mostrar pro banco o que deve ser alterado? É esse o meu problema.

Comment: Porque precisa disso em tela? Precisa no código. Não tem diferença alguma no código, é só não mostrar na tela.

Comment: Estou fazendo o programa em VB.NET. Os dados serão alterados a partir do que será inserido em caixas de texto. O ideal seria que o usuário colocasse um valor conhecido por ele, que fosse único e não pudesse sofrer alterações, pra fazer a alteração. Esse valor iria na condição 'WHERE'.

Comment: Você disse que essa informação não existe. Eu não faria assim, não tem necessidade alguma de fazer isto, mas se quer fazer desta forma então faça assim como descreveu. Não precisa nada disto, Estou votando para fechar a pergunta porque parece que ela não tem nada a ver com o que foi de fato perguntado. Não tem informações suficientes para responder.

Comment: @CatharinaLopes, não entendi muito bem o que você conhece sobre PK. Na citação **O ideal seria que o usuário colocasse um valor conhecido por ele, que fosse único e não pudesse sofrer alterações, pra fazer a alteração. Esse valor iria na condição 'WHERE'**, Isso viola as condições de PK , Uma PK é imutável, invariável, ou seja não pode ser `ALTERADA`. Você só precisar fazer seu `Selet * from tabela where id = 1;` e fazer o `Update tabela set campo1 = '', campo2 = '' where id = 1;`.

Answer (score 0):

O Id é pra controle interno do teu código com o banco... vc n precisa passar isso ou algo do gênero pro usuário.

Se ele vai alterar algo do banco, ele precisa saber oq quer alterar, teu código e banco saberão oq é pra alterar pelo Id.

Comment: Mas não é direto no banco, é a partir do programa. Exemplifiquei no texto da postagem, com o código de UPDATE.

Comment: exemplo: UPDATE tabela SET coluna(s) (coluna1, coluna2)
 VALUES ('VALORES', 'VALORES') 
WHERE ID(OU OUTRA COLUNA CONHECIDA PARA PESQUISA) ='ID_DA_SUA_TABELA ou VALOR_CONHECIDO_DA_PESQUISA '

Comment: claro que o ideal n é vc ir direto pro update..
faça um caminho pra ele:
primeiro ele procura oq quer alterar > altera
assim vc  faz um SELECT com a coluna q ele conhece > ele escolhe o que quer mudar > vc pega o ID do que ele quer mudar e no UPDATE vc usa o ID...

Isso evita que vc altere o  valor errado... digamos q ele queira mudar o CPF do joaozinho, se tem 2 joaozinhos, barro... com id isso n acontece

Comment: Claro que não, mas não estou com problemas com INSERT ou DELETE.